# Windows Phone silverlight - software buttons overlap

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-10-mobile

We have an issue with the bottom of all screens being cut off on some devices (please see screenshots).

The app is a Windows Phone 8.1 silverlight app, which we're running on Windows Phone 10 as well.

We can only reproduce this problem on Windows Phone 10 devices with software buttons at the bottom of the screen, as appose to hardware buttons (See screenshots of 830 & 550, both having the same resolution). We cannot reproduce the issue on Windows Phone 8.1 at all (the 635 does have software buttons although not shown in the screenshot).

Does anyone know any possible causes for this problem?

**Nokia Lumia 635 running Windows Phone 8.1**

[image]

**Nokia Lumia 830 running Windows 10 Mobile (10.0.14393.67)**

[image]

**Nokia Lumia 550 running Windows 10 Mobile (10.0.14393.67)**

[image]

**Notice the red bottom line going under the navigation bar.**

If the navigation bar is not present, it goes off the screen instead.

Comment: Having the same problem - though it happens not in the main app but in the CameraCaptureTask, leaving me without a workaround. Very curious to see if there's any solution to this.

Comment: @Simon did you find a solution? I am facing a related problem

Answer (score 0):

Simon, you have to set bottom Margin on button or Grid.

Comment: That's a work around and not a fix. If I set a bottom margin, it will fix it going off screen on Windows phone 10 devices but leave a big gap where it already works.